# Firebase Authentication - Forget/ Reset Password

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

I am adding the functionality of authentication to my app. I am using firebase [REST api](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password) for authentication. I am successful in implementing login, logout, signup etc functions. Now I want to implement forget or reset password.

I want to send the api request to firebase to generate the code and receive it at user's email. So that app can send back the code with the new password back to firebase for resetting.

I am not able to find the appropriate api from firebase documentation. Will anyone please advise?

Answer (score 2):

I'm right in the middle of working with password changing with Firebase myself, and though I'm not using Angular, here's the links to the two key methods needed for changing the password, from the FB Auth documentation.

From the docs, to send the email: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#sendpasswordresetemail

```
import { getAuth, sendPasswordResetEmail } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email)
  .then(() => {
    // Password reset email sent!
    // ..
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```

Once the user clicks the link in the email, they will end up on your site's email landing page (defined in the Auth email templates or through your custom third party email solution). The link will have a parameter "oobCode", which is needed to reset the password.

On that landing page, ask the user for a new password, and then pass the oobCode and the new password to the *confirmPasswordReset* function: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#confirmpasswordreset

```
import { getAuth, confirmPasswordReset } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const oobCode = [However Angular reads querystring values]('oobCode');
confirmPasswordReset (auth, oobCode)
  .then(() => {
    // Password has been reset!
    // ..
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, Scopique!
sendPasswordResetEmail() sends the reset link with oobcode in it.

I want to send only code but **NOT** link. My app has a custom page to reset the password and code can be entered there with new password.

Intended workflow is
1. enter email and press "generate code"
2. email code if the email is registered.
3. enter the code and new password on a custom page. Then submit to reset.

Comment: Hmmm. I think I understand: you just want the user to get an email with "your reset code is:XXXXXX" which they can copy and paste into a form along with their new password? Essentially what you'd be doing is taking the automation out of the process. However, I didn't see any info in the docs that tell how to get JUST the code and NOT put the code as part of a link in the email that the user is sent.

Google's Functions might help, or a third party email service, but those are currently beyond my knowledge.

Comment: You are right. I also could not figure out any simple way. Basically, I don't like the idea of diverting users to the firebase link for resetting the password. Anyways, as you said rightly, I am trying firebase functions to handle this part. Indeed, thanks to this challenge, I could explore the convenience and capability of functions. I'll post my solution once I am done.

Comment: I worked with the code of Scopique. It works for firebase 8, if you write "auth.confirmPasswordReset(code, newPassword).
For firebase 9 write "confirmPasswordReset(auth, code, newPassword)"